# Authentication Failed while sending email via gmail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email from my application, but getting authentication failed error again and again. I have tried the given solutions but they are not working, hence I thought to put my code. Please look at the below code and tell me if something important is missing.

```
package managimg.stud.data;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import sendmail.Sendmail;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendMail {
   public static void main(String...a){
      SendMail s = new SendMail();  
   }

   public SendMail(){

      Authenticator authenticate = new Authenticator(){
         public PasswordAuthentication getPasswrodAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication("abcd","xyz");
         }
      };

      String to = "toUser@gmail.com";
      String from = "abcd@gmail.com";
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true") ;
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true") ;
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "abcd"); 
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", "xyz");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,authenticate);

      try{

         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

Can anybody please tell me what is the problem here? What am I missing? I am again and again getting the below error. I have tried many solutions for this but it's not working. Can anybody please help me on this?

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at managimg.stud.data.SendMail.<init>(SendMail.java:139)
at managimg.stud.data.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:31)
```

Comment: Google changed the permission evaluation for sending emails with remote sender addresses via a gmail smtp server yesterday. You will find information about that in the internet along with alternatives and workarounds.

Comment: But i am able to ping the host . Now regarding the permissions can you please provide any link through which i can find the alternatives.

Comment: I have tried almost all the solutions given in the stack overflow to connect with gmail or any other mail server but no solution is working. Every  time i am getting the same error. can anyone please provide some feasible and correct solution. I have also tried simply copy and paste of the code mentioned over the internet from various sites but they are not working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I resolved my error. Please find the below code and just now I sent with one test email.

```
package gmail.email;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;


public class GmailEmail {

    final String userName ="pan54321@gmail.com";
    final String password="tqw12";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GmailEmail();
    }

    public GmailEmail(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true") ;
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true") ;

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }

        });

        try{
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("pan54321@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  InternetAddress.parse("vi@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("my First Email");
            message.setContent("<h:body>You wrote first email</body>","text/html;     charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(MessagingException
               messageException){
            throw new RuntimeException(messageException);
        }

    }

}
```

I have used only two jars:

1. mail.jar
2. javaee-api-6.0.jar

and MY JDK version is JDK6.0.